# Error RN :Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-render-html

I'm getting data from WordPress API and showing it in react native application. Getting this error only after adding  component even I'm trying to parse a simple paragraph. This is my code -

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import HTML from "react-native-render-html";
import globalStyles from "../constant/globalStyle";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import { Colors } from "../constant/colors";

class PostDetail extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: "Loading",
    imageUrl: "https://source.unsplash.com/random",
    content: "Loading",
    date: new Date().toString,
    loaded: false,
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    console.log("FETCHING");

    const req = await axios.get(
      `https://bachrasouthpanchayat.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${this.props.route.params.postId}?embed=true`
    );
    const response = req.data;

    console.log("UPDATING STATE");
    this.setState({
      title: response.title.rendered,
      date: response.date,
      content: response.content.rendered,
      loaded: true,
    });
    console.log("STATE UPDATEDDDDDD");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={{
          ...globalStyles.container,
          backgroundColor: Colors.BACKGROUND_SCREEN,
        }}
      >
        {this.state.loaded ? (
          <>
            {this.state.imageUrl ? (
              <Image
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  height: 250,
                }}
                source={{ uri: this.state.imageUrl }}
                resizeMode="cover"
              />
            ) : null}
            <Text style={globalStyles.primaryHeading}>{this.state.title}</Text>
            <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 18 }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...globalStyles.date,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: "700",
                }}
              >
                {moment(this.state.date).format("LL")}
              </Text>
              <HTML
                source={{ html: "<p>Hello World</p>" }}
                contentWidth={parseInt(Dimensions.get("window"))}
              />
            </View>
          </>
        ) : (
          <View
            style={{
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <ActivityIndicator size={60} color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN} />
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default PostDetail;
```

I want to use react-native-render-html package to render post content from wordpress but don't know why it's not rendering even a simple

tag :|

Comment: From the first sigh your component doesn't seem to have any issues. Could you please share the parent component as well - the component which renders your component

Comment: `react-native-render-html` is pretty unlikely to be responsible here since dozens of inline snippets are working as expected [in the Discovery App](https://expo.io/@jsamr/react-native-render-html-discovery) (those snippets are also available in the [documentation website](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/) via Expo Snacks). Most probably, the component causing this error is somewhere else in the React tree. Proceed by dichotomy : remove an element from the tree and see if the error disappears, starting from top to bottom.